# Problem with array inside a function C segmentation failed

Tags: c, arrays, permutation

I have this code (Sorry the spanish)
In the "perm()" function, if i use array, to put whatever is in "a", in the array, the console throw me segmentation failed, but when i only print "a", i don't have any issue, so i don't know how to use an array to save the permutations and then print it, not just print it in the function

```
`
/*
Cree un programa en C el cual solicite a un usuario una palabra de largo n (4 ó 5).
El programa debe generar todas las permutaciones de sus letras, por ejemplo, si el usuario ingresa
la palabra GATO, el programa deberá almacenar en una matriz y posteriormente mostrar las
siguientes combinaciones de letras
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//Funcion Factorial
int fact(int n){
    int i, mult;
    i=n;
    mult=1;
    if (n==0){
        mult=1;
    }
    else{
        while (i>0){
            mult=mult*i;
            i=i-1;
        }
    }
    return mult;
}
//Funcion Intercambiar
void cambio(char *a, char *b){
    char aux;
    aux=*a;
    *a=*b;
    *b=aux;
}
//Funcion Permutar
char **matriz;
int m=0;
void perm(char *a, int i, int n){
    int j;
        if (i==n){
          matriz[m]=a; //With this i have a problem
            printf("%s\n", a);
          m=m+1;
        }
        else{
            j=i;
            while (j<=n){
                cambio((a+i), (a+j));
                perm(a, i+1, n);
                cambio((a+i), (a+j));
                j=j+1;
            }
        }
    }



//Funcion principal
int main(){

    /* Pedirle la palabra al usuario y calcular el largo de esta */
    char *palabra;
    printf("Ingrese una palabra: ");
    scanf("%s", palabra); //Tengo la palabra
    int largo=0;
    while (palabra[largo]){
        largo=largo+1; //Tengo largo de la palabra
    }


    /* Pasar la palabra a un arreglo dinámico */
    char *letras=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char*)*largo);
    int i=0;
    while (i<largo){
        letras[i]=palabra[i];
        i=i+1;
    } 


    /* Sacar la cantidad de permutaciones */
    int nper;
    nper=fact(largo); //Tengo la cantidad de permutaciones


    /* Armar la matriz */
    char **matriz=(char**)malloc(sizeof(char*)*nper);
    i=0;
    while (i<nper){
        matriz[i]=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*largo);
        i=i+1;
    }


    /* Permutar(??) */
    perm(letras, 0, largo-1);


    /*Imprimir Permutaciones*/
    i=0;
    printf("Las %d permutaciones son\n", nper);
    printf("%d\n", m);
    printf("%c\n", letras[2]);
    while (i<nper){
        printf("%s", matriz[i]);
        i=i+1;
    }



    /* Liberar memoria */
    i=0;
    while (i<nper){
        free(matriz[i]);
        i=i+1;
    }
    free(matriz);
    free(letras);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char *palabra; scanf("%s", palabra);`. The `palabra` pointer is unintialised. That is, it doesn't point to valid memory. Writing to it results in undefined behaviour. Need to point it to a valid buffer first (e.g. obtained via `malloc` or local array variable).

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. If all you're having problems with is a single function, there is no point in posting all the other parts of the program that don't matter in that respect. Furthermore, cutting down on your program until only the error remains will help you in debugging it yourself.